# Recursive function within a run() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion

I would like to place a recursive function within a thread runnable run() method - here is an example fragment..

> ```
> yt[c] = new Thread (
>    new Runnable() {
>     public void run() {
>     /* recursive function here */
>     }
>     }
>  );
> ```

Is their any way to implement this within the run() method? Effectively embedding a method within a method (I'm assuming a recursive function has to be implemented as a method)?

As a trivial example say how would I implement n! within a run() method (recursively not iterated)? I am puzzled.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Effectively embedding a method within a method

Well, you won't embed the method in the `run` method itself. Rather just add one more method in addition to `run` and call it: -

```
new Thread (
   new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           /* recursive function here */
           fact(10);
        }

        private void fact(int n) {
            // logic
        }
    }
 );
```

Since with `new Runnable() { }`, you are just creating a anonymous class implementing the `Runnable` interface, so, there is no one stopping you from adding your own extra method. And probably you can also make it `private`, as you won't be using it from outside.

Comment: many thanks - I see now that the scope is within the runnable block and therefore visible to the run() function! Great reply.

Comment: Why not just call run?

Answer (score 2):

Just add another method to the `Runnable` (or anywhere else where you can call it from the `run()` method). There's really nothing special here that would make it hard to call a recursive method from a `run()` method.

```
yt[c] = new Thread (
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(compute(10L));
        }

        private long compute(long n) {
            if (n == 0) {
                return 1L;
            } else {
                return n * compute(n - 1L);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Appreciate the time required to code the function as well - trivial as it is - appreciated!